# Batch file for renaming - using if Exist without full path?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I am trying to write code to check if certain files have a backup named filename.bkp . If they do,  the code should rename the original file to filename.alt and then rename the backup filename. If no filename.bkp exists i want it to rename filename to filename.bkp and then rename filename.alt to filename.

I am writing this to share with a friend but I don't know his system's file structure. I was trying to write it to work from the batch's current directory as I have done before with renaming scripts. But it doesn't seem to work how I think it should. My script currently does nothing. I'm pretty sure my only problem is not knowing how to call the file without the full path!

Here is my code so far.

```
@if EXIST "left4dead2\pak01_dir.vpk.bkp" (for /r "left4dead2\" %%i in ("pak01_dir.vpk") do ren "%%~fi" "pak01_dir.vpk.alt" for /r "left4dead2\" %%i in ("pak01_dir.vpk.bkp") do ren "%%~fi" "pak01_dir.vpk") ELSE (for /r "left4dead2\" %%i in ("pak01_dir.vpk") do ren "%%~fi" "pak01_dir.vpk.bkp" for /r "left4dead2\" %%i in ("pak01_dir.vpk.alt") do ren "%%~fi" "pak01_dir.vpk")
@if EXIST "left4dead2\pak01_dir.vpk.bkp" (echo "Ready for Online Heads Will Roll Match") ELSE (echo "Returned to Default")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for /r` requires a `wildcard` in the target.
and your commands were not separated with an `&` in a single line, which is an error.
When splitting it into a multi-line batch file, it can look like this.

The way you were using it the batch file is in the same folder as the `left4dead2` folder.

```
@echo off
pushd "left4dead2"
if EXIST "pak01_dir.vpk.bkp" (
   for /r %%i in ("pak01_dir.vpk?")     do ren "%%i" "pak01_dir.vpk.alt" 
   for /r %%i in ("pak01_dir.vpk.bkp?") do ren "%%i" "pak01_dir.vpk"
) ELSE (
   for /r %%i in ("pak01_dir.vpk?")     do ren "%%i" "pak01_dir.vpk.bkp" 
   for /r %%i in ("pak01_dir.vpk.alt?") do ren "%%i" "pak01_dir.vpk"
)

if EXIST "pak01_dir.vpk.bkp" (
   echo "Ready for Online Heads Will Roll Match"
) ELSE (
   echo "Returned to Default"
)
popd
```

Comment: Works great except my echo's never show at the end and I'd really like it to tell my friend when it has returned to default and when it has changed! why would the script be running and closing even when i remove the echo off line?

Comment: Never mind I found it I need to add a pause might try a TIMEOUT! Thanks for your help it will make future coding a lot easier.

Comment: Odd the script still works without the ? wildcards but it echos a file can't be found line even though it still renames it!?

Comment: If you use it without the wildcard and replace the `ren` with `echo ren` then I think you will see that it returns every file and just tries to blindly rename it.